# Center page view Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

80% of the time we are working in Google Sheets like this one.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kYHghFZTyKxz_CpME0s1SaJdFo3AG8OSeWCi7Q-bAVE/edit#gid=274025131

It would be better if the content is in the middle of the page, as shown below, but it still needs to print fast.

How can we do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## solution 1:

- downsize the browser window and move it to the center:

  [image]

## solution 2:

- add a column to the left
- resize it so the actual desired content would be centered
- you can change background color to fake emptiness
- you can also create a **Group column** for fast hide/unhide/centering before printing

  [image]

  [image: 0]